# Strange error preventing application running on GlassFish from finding domain.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am unable to run applications on GlassFish server on Eclipse:

Error message on Eclipse:

> Unable to start server due following issues:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${sunappserver.rootdirectory}\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${sunappserver.rootdirectory}\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.glassfish.tools.ide.server.parser.TreeParser.readXml(TreeParser.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.tools.ide.server.ServerTasks.startServer(ServerTasks.java:164)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour$StartJob.call(GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour.java:671)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour$StartJob.call(GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${sunappserver.rootdirectory}\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.tools.ide.server.parser.TreeParser.readXml(TreeParser.java:102)
    ... 7 more
```

The `domain.xml` DOES exist in the location specified. Also, the GlassFish server works if I start it through asadmin.

I'm running Eclipse Kepler (SR2) with GlassFish tools and GlassFish 4 server.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you in any way entered `${sunappserver.rootdirectory}` somewhere?

Comment: I have the server runtime environments setup to point to the glassfish directory, so I assumed ${sunappserver.rootdirectory} will point to that location.. do I need to define this value explicitly elsewhere?

Comment: Probably, or you cannot enter it where you did.  Reread the documentation about what you want to do _very_ carefully.